# onclick events with Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My client is using Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics, and would like to be able to track the views for the videos on their website. Their videos are YouTube videos that are displayed in a shadowbox/lightbox via an onclick event.

I added a second onclick event to the same div that opens the shadlowbox, but the datalayer.push events are not appearing in the Analytics reports. I've included my onclick script below:

```
<div onclick="OpenVideo( 'S6cPlRkiKTw', 'youtube' );dataLayer.push({'eventCategory' : 'videos', 'eventAction' : 'click', 'eventLabel' : ’The Title of the Video', 'event' : 'shadowboxVideo'});”>
```

The "OpenVideo" function opens the video in the shadowbox and this is working fine, but the clicks are not being tracked in the Analytics reports.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my script or have any other suggestions?  Because the client wants to see the title of the video in the reports, I can't think of any other way to do this other than using onclick events, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing variables to the datalayer does not by itself send any data to Google Analytics. You need a Google Analytics tag with the type of "Event Tracking" in the tag manager and "event equals shadowboxVideo" as firing rule.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I had previously created a new tag like you suggested, but maybe I did something wrong.  I've included a link to a screenshot showing this tag in Tag Manager. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/251322/screenshot.png

Comment: That looks alright. When I tested the code fragment from your post I found that is uses wrong quotation marks at two occasions (which results in a js error which would prevent tracking) - is that an artefact from the stackoverflow editor or are those actual errors (talking about the closing double quotation mark and the one in front of ’The Title of the Video') ?

Answer (score 0):

Are there a lot of videos? You could potentially just listen for the element url and then create a rule in UA which replaces a Youtube URL with the title. I have it set up for a client where they just want to know the URL.
Also why not use autoevents in GTM instead of hardcoding?

Comment: Yes, there are probably over a hundred videos.  Unfortunately, they are all "activated" by an onclick event that is attached to a DIV.  In other words, there isn't an HREF value… just the video ID in the on click event shown in my original post.  Because of the way that they built the website, I don't think it will be possible to use the autoevents in GTM… I'm almost positive that I'll need to hardcode them.